# How to vertically align incomplete verses in a poem (theater style)?

Tags: css, text-alignment

In some poems, often in theater-like writing, the end of an incomplete verse must be aligned to the begin of the continuing, like that:

[image: Screenshot of the desired behaviour]

The verse that is split is vertically aligned as if it weren't split.

I'm creating an ebook, and I need a trick to make the CSS consistent for any font, size, etc. (because they are tweakable) without relying on monospace.

Is this possible at all? I've thought about it, but I've had no idea, not even a lead.

For now, the HTML looks like that:

```html
<div class="character">La Nourrice</div>
 
<p>Tu vis ! ou vois-je ici l’ombre d’une princesse ?
    <br/>À mes lèvres tes doigts et leurs bagues et cesse
    <br/>De marcher dans un âge ignoré...</p>
 
<div class="character">Hérodiade</div>
 
<p>Reculez.
    <br/>Le blond torrent de mes cheveux immaculés
    <br/>Quand il baigne mon corps solitaire le glace</p>
```

Comment: It would help to know if you have any freedom over code and what limitations does the ebook give you in terms of compatibility.

Comment: @MihailMinkov I can change the markup whatever I want. I'd like not to rely on javascript scripting (but if there is no CSS solution, I'll use that, it's easy).

Answer (score 0):

Within pre tag text will be displayed exactly as written by you

```html
  <div>
    <pre style="font-family: sans-serif;">
              La Nourrice
    Tu vis ! ou vois-je ici l’ombre d’une princesse ?
    À mes lèvres tes doigts et leurs bagues et cesse
    De marcher dans un âge ignoré...

            Hérodiade
                                      Reculez.
    Le blond torrent de mes cheveux  immaculés
    Quand il baigne mon corps solitaire le glace
    </pre>          
  </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If you change the font, you also change the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to do something similar is using `direction: rtl;` and a fixed width. In this case your main problem is that there's currently no way to force justify elements in CSS something that would be useful for this. Also, `<br>` tags break `text-align: justify` so in the case of the unfinished line I left the `<br>` but for the others I left it out. Even so, it looks a little weird.

There's a `::first-line` CSS property, but unfortunately it can't use `text-align`.

There's also `text-justify` but it's not confirmed as a supported property yet, so it's not working. It could solve your problem if it becomes official though. You can check more on it on [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify).

I'd suggest you revise your html structure if you can and have control over that part. Otherwise you don't have many options on this.

```css
p {
  max-width: 320px;
  display: block;
  text-align: justify;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<div class="character">La Nourrice</div>

<p>Tu vis ! ou vois-je ici l’ombre d’une princesse ?
  <br/>À mes lèvres tes doigts et leurs bagues et cesse
  <br/>De marcher dans un âge ignoré...</p>

<div class="character">Hérodiade</div>

<p>Reculez.<br> Le blond torrent de mes cheveux immaculés Quand il baigne mon corps solitaire le glace</p>
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I didn't notice it when I posted, but without changing the structure this is the one that looks the most similar. He could just put the dots in the beginning of the sentences.